# Full text not showing in Telegram Chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, telegram, telegram-bot

I have created a Multi-turn QNA chatbot using Microsoft Bot framework v4.5.
I integrate this chatbot with Telegram channel.
Issue in Telegram Channel:
1) When i have follow up prompt in answer then Full text is not showing,instead its showing (...)
Same code i tested in Emulator and webchat its working perfectly.

I have used below github code.
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/70.qnamaker-multiturn-sample

Attaching screenshot from telegram:
[image]

Comment: What Telegram client is that? Is it iPhone? Have you tested in other clients like the Windows desktop client? https://desktop.telegram.org/

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/2268

Comment: @kyle Delaney, I checked in desktop client as well, it's showing same as attached screenshot.

Comment: It looks like you're encountering the problem with some answers and not others. Can you provide some sample data that we can use to reproduce the problem? Please create a minimal example, especially if your data contains sensitive information.

Comment: Are you still working on this?